# Changing levels name in R

Tags: r, statistics

My data set has a variable "Gender" with levels "Man" and "Woman".
I want to change "Man" and "Woman" into "M" and "W" respectively. How can I do it in R?

Comment: Maybe you want this: `levels(df$Gender) <- list(M = "Man", W = "Woman")`?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use a factor and change the labels of the levels:

```r
my_data <- data.frame(gender = c("Man", "Woman"))
my_data$gender = factor(my_data$gender, levels = c("Man", "Woman"), labels = c("M", "W"))
```

Comment: Thanks, I did it in my data set but it vary all column's gender into NA. I don't know what the problem is

Comment: Is your column already a factor? Are the values definitely capitalised? If you share a sample of your data using `dput()` we're more likely to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

a solution using ifelse:

```
factor(ifelse(YOUR_VECTOR=="Man","M","W"))
```

Comment: Again it changes into NA . :(